# Delete information in the background firebase database EXPO

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, background-task

I have a project managed by the expo, I need to delete information in the firebase database after 10 seconds that I receive a Push notification, the task needs to be performed even if the screen is off.

Answer (score 1):

You can't perform action in firebase if your screen off.
Thus what you can do is using firebase Function in order to delete the information you want in the databse.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions

Comment: does it mean that I cannot use a database in the background in my application?